# Select image to post by capturing from smartphone camera

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html

How to let user capture image and post it by using users smartphone camera in angularjs single page application? I've tried HTML5 tag media capture and also a few jQuery functions which is only allowing me to browse image but not letting me select taken picture on the spot from my camera.

Answer (score 0):

Which mobile browser are you using? Android or iOS?

Did you tried the HTML5 Media Capture in this way:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Comment: it will be for both smartphone devices Android and iOS, i didnt mentioned accept image, else i have done, let me try by mentioning this too.